# грамотное написание. сопроводительное письмо

Tags: грамотная-речь

Мы направляем Вам документы в соответствии с требованиями проведенной проверки, на основании Приказа от 29 июня 2015 г. №261.

Comment: А как Приказ соотносится с проверкой? Это не очень ясно из текста.

Comment: изначально издали Приказ "о проведении проверки" , потом состоялась проверка, выявили нарушения и сказали собрать определенные документы...Но просто документы не отправишь...необходимо сопроводительное письмо ,ну вот собственно я его напечатала

Comment: К чему относятся "требования" - эта проверка по каким-либо правилам требует отсылки документов или имеется в виду выполненное требование провести проверку (на основании того приказа)?

Comment: эта проверка требует отсылки документов

Comment: на основании приказа была проведена проверка

Comment: Результаты проверки должны оформляться письменно, тогда Ваши документы  должны направлятьсяв соответствии с протоколом этой проверки.

Comment: нет протокола ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*В соответствии с требованиями проверки, **проведенной** на основании Приказа [...], мы направляем вам **следующие** документы: [далее перечень отправляемых документов]*

Если вы воспользуетесь такой формой, то сможете избежать кучи недоразумений, если вдруг какой-то из документов в ходе делопроизводства будет утерян.

Comment: Да, хороший вариант.

Comment: Лучше, по-моему, убрать "мы" плюс вместо "вам" написать "в ваш адрес".

Comment: Марк Из, это не "лучше", это почти что обязательное требование, я "на автомате" даже забыл упомянуть. А вот слово "следующие" здесь не по стилю. Вы же не академический отчет пишете, а отписку для кабинетной крысы. Если уж очень хотите что-то такое вставить, то "нижеперечисленные" или даже  "нижепоименованные".

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном вами предложении все нормально.

Comment: сорри я опечаталась, логично направлЯЕМ.... смысловая нагрузка , стиль написания ...вот в чем вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаемый текст:

Мы направляем Вам документы в соответствии с требованиями проверки, проведенной на основании Приказа от 29 июня 2015 г. №261.

Answer (score 1):

@Inesssaaa,
~1. Не волнуйтесь, письма сопроводительные никто не читает, когда понятен смысл (что именно направляют).

~2. Ваш вариант, равно как и предложенный, содержит двусмысленность в отношении того, что это за "требования", и их соотнесения с проверкой.
Откуда вообще взялись "требования"? Кто их устанавливал? Если это было оговорено в Приказе (на основании которого проверка производилась) или в каком-то документе, на который приказ ссылается, то это не требование проверки, а требование приказа.

По-русски это будет, например,так:

> *В соответствии с требованиями к **проведению** проверки, осуществленной на основании Приказа (такого-то), направляем Вам документы.*

Дальше обычно идет перечисление отправляемого - в нем, собственно, и заложен смысл такой сопроводиловки.

Если же "требование"  диктуется получателем документов (хотя обычно это называется "запрос"), то нужно добавить слово "Ваши", но даже в этом случае мотивацию лучше вынести в начало (бюрократы так любят фразу строить):

> *По вашему требованию направляем Вам результаты, осуществленной на основании Приказа (такого-то), направляем Вам документы проверки, проведенной на основании приказа (такого-то)*

Еще обратите внимание, если подписывает письмо руководитель предприятия, то он пишет **направляю**, "направляем" - это от коллектива. Аналогично, если получатель - руководитель, то направляю/направляем **Вам**, иначе - **вам**.

Но, как сказал, это все высокая бюрократическая материя, из-за простого письма не стоит и огород городить, если только начальник не лютует. Мне за свою жизнь приходилось столько абсолютно безграмотных писюлек в руках держать - ничего, никому по шапке не дали.)))